# Oracle Procedure - How to insert every combination of records into a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

I have an Oracle procedure I am working on that needs to insert every combination of Customers and Products into a specific table based on the CustomerIDs passed into the parameter.

Inputs:

Customers parameter (p_customers - comma separated):
IE: (1,2,3,4)

Order parameter (p_order - single value)

Output table that I must write to:

CustomerID, ProductID

I am hoping the following query will get me a list of the products that need be inserted:

```
select ProductID from orders where order_id = p_order_id
```

What is the most efficient way to write the insert statement?

Thank you!

Comment: If `p_customer` is a comma-separated string, the query you posted will not return any results (unless you have a customer whose `customerid` is the string "1,2,3,4").  Normally, you'd pass in a collection rather than a comma-separated list.  If you have to accept a comma-separated list, you'd normally parse that list to create the collection in your procedure.  In either of those cases, you could use the collection to do your cross-join.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to accept p_customer as a comma separated string. How would I do the cross join to make the inserts?

Comment: How are you actually using the comma-separated string in your query, then?  As I said, the query you posted cannot work.  If you actually have a query that works, that implies that you are actually already parsing the comma-separated list into some sort of collection, in which case you may be able to use that collection to do your cross join depending on the type of collection you chose, or that you are really using dynamic SQL to build the `select` query you posted which would be problematic on a number of levels.

Comment: Not understanding your requirement. Do you really mean a `CROSS JOIN`, aka Cartesian join, which would mean every combination?  If it's every combination, then why do you then also have the "query ... list of the products that need to be inserted"?  Is it that you want a few customers, such as (1,2,3,4) crossed with all the products for each customer related from the `orders` table?

Comment: I am using the p_customer string in a different part of the procedure by processing the customer records one at a time by using the Oracle instr and searching for commas.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to write this in psuedo code with an example by changing table names / columns from the real example. I updated the query accordingly.

Comment: I think I understand a bit more now.  So you want to put as input the `order_id`, and then have as output the `customer_id`,`product_id` from that one order.  Still unclear why you want to process the customer records one at a time.

Comment: Joshua - exactly! There is a different, unrelated, part of the procedure where I need to process the customer records one a time. For this part, if I could batch the insert somehow it would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your "pseudo" code, try something like this.  I ripped off parts of this from http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/delimited_lists_to_collections.html

Assuming these structures:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    orderId    VARCHAR2(100) primary key
  , customerId VARCHAR2(100)
  , productId  VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE output_table (customerId VARCHAR2(100), productId VARCHAR2(100));
```

Code:

```
CREATE TYPE varchar_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION csv_convert(p_list IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN varchar_table
AS
  l_string       VARCHAR2(32767) := p_list || ',';
  l_comma_index  PLS_INTEGER;
  l_index        PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  l_tab          varchar_table := varchar_table();
BEGIN
  LOOP
    l_comma_index := INSTR(l_string, ',', l_index);
    EXIT WHEN l_comma_index = 0;
    l_tab.EXTEND;
    l_tab(l_tab.COUNT) := SUBSTR(l_string, l_index, l_comma_index - l_index);
    l_index := l_comma_index + 1;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_tab;
END csv_convert;
/
```

A simple unit test of the newly created `csv_convert` function:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(csv_convert('1,2,3,4'));

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
1
2
3
4
```

Now the stored proc that makes use of the `csv_convert` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cust_products_process (p_customers IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO output_table (customerId, productId)
    SELECT customerId, productId
      FROM orders o
      JOIN TABLE(csv_convert(p_customers)) c
        ON (o.customerId = c.column_value);
END;
/
```

Comment: Joshua - THANK YOU! This code looks like it will do exactly what I need it to. I really like your approach with using the function to convert from csv to rows. I appreciate your response and will add this to the existing procedure tomorrow to try it. THANK YOU again!